# count NA's appearing in between non-missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I have a data frame with 5 time columns (1st year, second y, etc), and for some rows I have NA's in between non-missing values. Sample below:

```
df = structure(list(FirstYStage = c(NA, 3.2, 3.1, NA, NA, 2, 1, 3.2, 
3.1, 1, 2, 5, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3.1, 1), SecondYStage = c(NA, 
3.1, 3.1, NA, NA, 2, 1, 4, 3.1, 1, NA, 5, 3.1, 3.2, 2, 3.1, NA, 
2, 3.1, 1), ThirdYStage = c(NA, NA, 3.1, NA, NA, 3.2, 1, 4, NA, 
1, NA, NA, 3.2, NA, 2, 3.2, NA, NA, 2, 1), FourthYStage = c(NA, 
NA, 3.1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, 
2, 1), FifthYStage = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3.2, NA, 2, 3.2, NA, NA, 2, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I would like to count, using dplyr, the number of rows that have missing values in between non-missing values. Rows 13, 14,and 16 are examples of this.

How can I achieve this? I have a feeling this has to do with `paste`ing the entire row and looking to the left and to the right of the NA... but not clear how to proceed with this.

Comment: So you want your output to be 13, 14 and 16?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Or just 3 (the count)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sum(grepl("[[:digit:]]+[NA]+[[:digit:]]", apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "")))

[1] 3
```

In short:

1. concatenate the rows
2. check which rows return `TRUE` for having a match to the string: "number-NA-number" (in this case, row `13`, `14` and `16`)
3. sum the rows which evaluate to `TRUE`

Based on @ Sotos comment, this is even better since it prevents us from using `apply` with `margin = 1`:

```
sum(grepl("[[:digit:]]+[NA]+[[:digit:]]", do.call(paste0, df)))
```

Comment: Nice answer. FYI, you can omit the (horrible) `apply(...margin = 1, ...)` with the vectorized `do.call`, i.e., `do.call(paste0, df)`

Comment: @Lennyy do you also know of such a way to tell whether the number before the NA was smaller than the one after it, or vice-versa?

Comment: I might have some general ideas, but you would mind to post a new question (along with expected output) for this issue so we could keep this topic clean?

Comment: @Lennyy done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491759/progression-of-non-missing-values-that-have-missing-values-in-between